# How to Add pdf File as an Attachment to an Email

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am dynamically storing each person report as `pdf` and should send it to them an email `Attacment`. How do I send it as an attachment to an email. Here is my code.

```
public void Esendmail(string EmailFrom, string EmailTo, 
                      string EmailBody, string EmailSubject, string EmailCC)
{
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(EmailFrom);
            message.CC.Add(EmailCC);

            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(EmailTo));
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = EmailBody;
            message.Subject = EmailSubject;

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();

            client.Send(message);

 }
```

Answer (score 16):

Use this sample code

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To = "abc@domain.com";
message.From = "xyz@domain.com";
message.Subject = "mail with pdf";
message.Body = "your pdf attached";
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(@"c:\pdftoattach.pdf"));

SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "mail.domain.com";
SmtpMail.Send(message);
```

Answer (score 4):

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
FileStream fileStream = File.Create("PdfPath");
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
fileStream.Position = 0;
fileStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream,Path.GetFileName("PdfPath")));
```